# How to create an interface for this prototype?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a code with PIXI js and typescript. I try extend PIXI.Point but get exception:

> TS2339: Property 'Multiply' does not exist on type 'Point'.

```
   PIXI.Point.prototype.Multiply = function (value: number) {
        this.x *= value;
        this.y *= value;
        return this;
    };

    const test = new PIXI.Point(1, 1);
    console.log(test.Multiply(2));
```

How to fix it?

I tried another method, but result same
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not really good to mutate prototypes of existing constructors. Instead I'd like to suggest inherit Point:

```
class MyPoint extends PIXI.Point {
    Multiply(value: number) {
        this.x *= value;
        this.y *= value;
        return this;
    };
}
```

Comment: i don't want create another class

Comment: i want add new functional to PIXI.Point

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich ok, maybe you could consider using mixins? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html